# What is the probability that there are $k$ people between $A$ and $B$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

> If $n$ people are randomly seated in a row and two of the people are $A$ and $B$, what is the probability that there are $k$ people between $A$ and $B$ ($A$ can be either to the left or right of $B$)?

Is this the expected value of the uniform distribution, since I guess we can assume that there are equally likely to be $1$ person between $A$ and $B$ as there are to be a million?

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts. 
You are more likely to receive positive/constructive feedback that way.  
Formatting your post helps too.
Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The answer will be expressed in terms of $n$ as well as $k$.  If the row holds ten people, there is no chance there could be one million people between $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: There are $\binom{n}2$ equally likely pairs of positions for $A$ and $B$. For $k=0,\ldots,n-2$, how many of those pairs have exactly $k$ positions between them? If you don’t see it fairly quickly, work out all of the possibilities with $n=5$ and $n=6$ by hand; the pattern should become apparent rather quickly.

Answer (score 0):

There are $n!$ ways to seat the $n$ people in a row, each of which is equally likely.

For $0 \le k \le n - 2$, there are $2 \times \left[n - (k + 2) + 1\right] = 2(n - k - 1)$ ways to seat A and B with $k$ seats between them. For each of those seating arrangements, there are $(n - 2)!$ ways to seat the remaining $n - 2$ people. By the multiplication principle, there are $2(n - k - 1)(n - 2)!$ ways to seat the $n$ people such that there are $k$ people between A and B.

Therefore, the probability that there are $k$ people between A and B is $$\frac{2(n - k - 1)(n - 2)!}{n!} = \frac{2(n - k - 1)}{n(n - 1)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

If there is no one between the duo, they can be placed in $(n-1)$ combos

so if there are $k$ people between them, they can be positioned in $(n-k-1)$ combos,
against a total of $\binom{n}{2}$ possible combos,

thus $Pr = \dfrac{(n-k-1)}{\dbinom{n}{2}}$

**Note** that we didn't need to distinguish between $A$ and $B$, as we only need to compute **Pr**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer to this question but I don't know if it is correct.

First, let's deal with the number of combinations of placing the two people A and B. When you ask what are the number of ways of placing two things, among n things such that they are never consecutive, it is equivalent to picking those two things out and then choosing any two $n-2+1 ways = \binom{n-1}{2}$

Now, the question of the number of people in between them. They go from 1 to n-2. Since, the people themselves don't matter, it doesn't matter which k people are sitting in between them. So, we don't have to work out the number of ways of choosing these k people. So now we work out how many ways it is possible to choose these k people, + A and B in a block. How many ways of selecting k+2 consecutive people among n people ? (N-k-2)

So according to me, the answer is

$\frac{ N - k - 2}{\binom{N-1}{2}}$